# Inserting a PDF Comment with pandoc

Tags: pdf, pandoc

What's the easiest way to insert a PDF comment attached to a block of markdown? I discovered [pdfcomment](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment) but don't know how to use it with pandoc (or if that's even possible).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your workflow and what you want to achieve? E.g.: are you writing MD and converting into LaTeX? Or you are using LaTeX with `markdown` package and need to convert your code into another format via pandoc?

Comment: @Iacobus1983 I am writing MD and converting to PDF via pandoc. I know pandoc uses LaTeX internally.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using pandoc `raw_tex` extension. The steps should be:

1. Within your md source, you write the comments using LaTex `pdfcomment` syntax.
2. You modify pandoc template for pdf adding in its preamble `\usepackage{pdfcomment}` (see pandoc manual for details).
3. You run `pandoc -f markdown+raw_tex -t pdf`